# Configure Thorntail logging to System.out

Tags: docker, logging, thorntail

In a Thorntail project, the logging configuration for CONSOLE works as expected:

```
thorntail:
  logging:
    pattern-formatters:
      LOG_FORMATTER:
        pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"
    console-handlers:
      CONSOLE:
        named-formatter: LOG_FORMATTER
        target: console
    root-logger:
      handlers:
      - CONSOLE
```

In a Docker environment I need to output the logs using **System.out**. According to the [documentation](https://docs.thorntail.io/2.4.0.Final/#_logging_3), the target key has three possible values:

> **thorntail.logging.console-handlers.KEY.target**
>
> Defines the target of the console handler. The value can be **System.out**, **System.err** or **console**.

I did change my target to System.out as follows:

```
thorntail:
  logging:
    pattern-formatters:
      LOG_FORMATTER:
        pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"
    console-handlers:
      CONSOLE:
        named-formatter: LOG_FORMATTER
        target: System.out
    root-logger:
      handlers:
      - CONSOLE
```

And then I get this exception where one of the possible values is the one I configured...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value 'System.out'; should be one of: console,System.out,System.err
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure where's the problem, but `System.out` is the default value per https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/7.0.0.Final/logging/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/logging/handlers/ConsoleHandlerResourceDefinition.java#L51, so you can just leave the `target` out completely.

Comment: Thank you @Ladicek! This worked like a charm! You can answer the question and I will give it as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where's the problem, but `System.out` is the default value per https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/7.0.0.Final/logging/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/logging/handlers/ConsoleHandlerResourceDefinition.java#L51, so you can just leave the `target` out completely.